# How to disable bursting on Google Cloud Platfrom shared CPU instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to do some bench marking analysis.

I would like to benchmark against an instance (`g1-small` for example) that is being throttled (exhausted it's burst credits). Is there a way I can prevent a compute instance from bursting while being benchmarked?

I'm looking for an simpler way to prevent bursting than stressing the CPU, running the benchmark and ensuring it does not go over it's CPU allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the bursting of vCPUs is not available at this time, the instances are allowed to burst for a short period as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#sharedcore). A feature to disable bursting can be requested through the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1011214).