# Google Cloud Platform free tier charging for burst on f1-micro instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using GCP Free tier's f1-micro instance. I noticed that I'm being charged for the "Micro Instance with burstable CPU running in Americas" so I imagine that my application is too heavy for that instance. Still, is there a way to block these bursts and/or avoid unwanted costs?

Comment: F1-micro is not part of the Free Tier. e2-micro is in certain regions. Read this document for details: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMs offer bursting capabilities that allow instances to use additional physical CPU for short periods of time. Bursting happens automatically when your instance requires more physical CPU than originally allocated. During these spikes, your instance will opportunistically take advantage of available physical CPU in bursts. Note that bursts are not permanent and are only possible periodically. **Bursting doesn't incur any additional charges**([source](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing)) And note that your Free Tier instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all your instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. Usage calculations are combined across the supported regions.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756624/is-f1-micro-vm-machine-type-forever-free) stackoverflow question:

**There is a recent UPDATE** : From August 1st, 2021, the Free Tier F1-micro VM is changing to the E2-micro VM as the VM to use for free. On August 1, 2021, E2-micro Free Tier will be introduced. Follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#before-you-begin) to change your machine type to E2-micro to avoid incurring charges for continuing to use F1-micro after August 31, 2021.

Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing) for more information of charges applied on f1-micro Instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to prevent bursting according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006174/how-to-disable-bursting-on-google-cloud-platfrom-shared-cpu-instances) question asked before.